# How to extract email-ID from google login api?

Tags: html, google-oauth, google-signin

I was implementing google login in building my web application. There I have kept an option of google login but I need to know that the logged in user is an existent user of my application otherwise he will have to sign-up first.

So I need to know the email-ID and match it with my database.

This I know works for most web applications but I haven't found any source code for that and I think its hard to code it out myself the portion of getting the email-ID.

Here is the google-login api I used:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
          Google Sign in Page
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="540496349919-20gn1hjm7i265i27rs9d3dchjv45ni33.apps.googleusercontent.com">
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <style>
           .g-signin2 {
           margin-left: 500px;
           margin-top: 200px;
           }
           .data {
              display: none;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onsignin"></div> 

Here on log in  I will match the user's email-ID with my database list of email-ID's, if not present, he has to register and be directed to a page(say signup.php), if present, he will be directed to his page(say profile.php)

         <div class="data">
            <button onclick="signout()" class="btn btn-danger"> Sign Out </button>
    </body>

</html>
```

How to get the email-ID of the logged-in user?

Comment: Answered Check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have signed in a user with `Google` using the default scopes, you can **access** the user's Google ID, name, profile URL, and email address.

To retrieve profile information for a user, use the getBasicProfile() method.

```
// auth2 is initialized with gapi.auth2.init() and a user is signed in.

    if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
      var profile = 
      auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
      console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
      console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
    }
```